# Add content if the element is not empty

Tags: html, css

I want to add content (with :before selector) only if span has value.

If the span is empty I don't want to add content with :before selector.

How can I do it with css?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    span.b::before {
      content: "\2022"
    }
    
    .span.b:empty {}
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="a">
    <span class="b">AAA</span>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close. You're looking for:

```
span.b:not(:empty)::before {
  content:"\2022"
}
```

```css
span.b:not(:empty)::before {
  content:"\2022"
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <span class="b">AAA</span>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <span class="b"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a code like this

```
span.b::before {
    content: "\2022";
}
span.b:empty::before {
    content: inherit;
}
```

You can use the property `inherit` to give the default styles. Because it's normally inherit. But if the browser don't know the value `inherit` for any propery, you can use it likes `initial`